# PDOException in Connector.php line 47: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'hassan'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, cpanel

I am trying to upload website on cpanel. The following error is encountering

> PDOException in Connector.php line 47: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access
>   denied for user 'hassan'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

My .env file contains:

```
    APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=4ZuW70AMILLsnvHkTJ1yraRoGqmx4Dzg

    DB_HOST=localhost
    DB_DATABASE=campaign
    DB_USERNAME=hassan
    DB_PASSWORD=password

    CACHE_DRIVER=file
    SESSION_DRIVER=file
    QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

    MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
    MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
    MAIL_PORT=2525
    MAIL_USERNAME=null
    MAIL_PASSWORD=null
```

and config/database.php as

```
    'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'campaign'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'hassan'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'China125'),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,]
```

What might be wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

The second paramater of `env` function contains a default value, which is used if the needed constant is not found.

In your case, you specify constant `DB_PASSWORD` and use value `password`.

Did you intend to use value `China125`?

Either remove that constant completely from `.env` file in order to use your default, or set it to `China125`:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=campaign
DB_USERNAME=hassan
DB_PASSWORD=China125
```

Comment: Just check settings of your database then