# Laravel PDOException error in Connector.php line 55

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am beginner in **Laravel PHP framework**.That's why i am trying basic task from [HERE (Laravel.com)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart#introduction) .I followed this basic task step by step.But after finishing this i am getting an *error*. I am putting the *error* here.

> PDOException in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\quickstart\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php
> line 55: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user
> 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

What is the meaning of this error?

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Here is my **.env** file.

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

I have found similar problem in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30200208/pdoexception-in-connector-php-line-47-sqlstatehy000-1045-access-denied-for). But there is no proper solution of it.

Here i add few lines *(48 to 63)* from **Connector.php** .

```
public function createConnection($dsn, array $config, array $options)
{
    $username = Arr::get($config, 'username');

    $password = Arr::get($config, 'password');

    try {
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $pdo = $this->tryAgainIfCausedByLostConnection(
            $e, $dsn, $username, $password, $options
        );
    }

    return $pdo;
}
```

Really I do get right solution of it. Can anyone give me the right solution to it? BTW this is laravel 5.2.

Comment: Is your `.env` file readable/in the right position? because if it's not, Laravel will default to what's written in the `config/database.php` file. There's nothing wrong in your Connector.php, as the error clearly states Laravel's using some other kind of configs

Comment: i am also adding database details in `config/database.php` but it was not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

This means, that your provided username and password is incorrect. If you're using homestead, default username ir `homestead` and the password is `secret`. Also, You might need to change the database port, since the default laravel configuration will look for port `3306`, but homestead runs on port `33060`

So the **.env** file should look like this:

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
DB_PORT=33060
```

[Source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead#daily-usage)

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove this file in the directory:

```
bootstrap/cache/config.php
```

Or run this in the terminal:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to install php module for **pdo_mysql**

to do that run this command on your server

`yum install php-mysqlnd`

Then restart httpd service

`service httpd restart`