# route return view gives error Laravel 5

Tags: php, view, laravel-5, routes

I am getting returning string from that **checkCookie** controller class method. So why this snippet gives me error??

```
Route::get('mypage',function(Request $request){
    $a=new App\Http\Controllers\indexController;
    $b=$a->checkCookie($request);
    if(!empty($b)){
        return view('mypage');
    }
});
```

Comment: **C:\xampp\htdocs\l5\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php line 55:**  at that line i have this `$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);`

Comment: i checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34740908/laravel-pdoexception-error-in-connector-php-line-55 but i m not using homestead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution (https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-php-artisan-migrate-problem?page=1). so i have changed my **.env** file settings equal to **config/database.php** now my **.env** file look like:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE='db_name'
DB_USERNAME='root'
DB_PASSWORD=''
DB_PORT=3306
```